# Using find and copy modules in Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I would know how to use find and copy modules.

When I run the following code, I'm getting an error.

Probably I'm not using register correct.

```
- name: ACP Collection 2
  find:
    path: "{{item}}"
    recurse: yes
    patterns: '*.log'
  with_items:
    - '/usr/'
    - '/opt/tomcat/logs/'
    - '/var/'
    - '/root/'
    - '/opt/allot/'        
  register: files_to_copy

- name: copy files to tmp
  copy:
    src: "{{item}}"
    dest:  /data/Snapshot/ACP/ 
  with_items: files_to_copy.results
```

Please advice.

Comment: 1) What's the error message? 2) Take a look at the data *- debug: msg="{{ files_to_copy }}"* .

Comment: The error was: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Where does the 'endswith' come from? I can't find it in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over paths in find module. Loop returns a list of results and from each result, you need to traverse again on the list which is returned by single `find` execution. Instead of that, you can give a list of paths to `find` module. That will make things easier. Then you need to only iterate over `files_to_copy.files` instead of `files_to_copy.results`

```
- name: ACP Collection 2
  find:
    paths:
      - '/usr/'
      - '/opt/tomcat/logs/'
      - '/var/'
      - '/root/'
      - '/opt/allot/' 
    recurse: yes
    patterns: '*.log'
  register: files_to_copy

- name: copy files to tmp
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest:  /data/Snapshot/ACP/ 
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```

Comment: I'm getting the following ERROR:
failed: [single-node-with-mstr] (item=files_to_copy.files) => {"failed": true, "item": "files_to_copy.files", "msg": "Unable to find 'files_to_copy.files' in expected paths."}

Comment: my bad .. i missed braces. now i have updated the answer.

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py", line 66, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/__init__.py", line 58, in path_has_trailing_slash
    return path.endswith('/')

Comment: The error was: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: can you debug files_to_copy after first task and check the find results.  and can you also try to remove trailing slashes list of paths and also from destination field in copy command

Comment: How do i debug files_to_copy ?
Can you assist me with this ?
(I'm beginner in ansible)